# android admob multiple activities

Tags: java, android, admob

I have a small app with 3 activities with `admob` banner in each of them.
Banner loads in `onCreate()` function, so when user navigating between activities, banner not showing for a few seconds.

What can I do to prevent reloading banner after changing current activity?

Comment: I think you can't keep the current state of the ad